# Architecture for a RESTful web service with a single thread executor?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, lifecycle, executor

I would like to know what could be the best architecture for a RESTful web service with a **single thread** executor.

My goal :

1. Call a RESTful web service
2. The web service add a task in a thread queue and execute all the task 1 per 1.

The life cyle of instanciated object is really important (there must be **only one thread queue**). I know that a RESTful web service life cycle is "per request" (similar to @RequestScoped I think), so I see 2 options :

Option 1 :

```
public class RestService {
    protected final static Executor executor;
    protected final static Implementation1 impl1;
    protected final static Implementation2 impl2;

    static {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        impl1 = new Implementation1();
        impl2 = new Implementation2();
    }
}

@Path("/servicename")
public class MyService extends RestService {
    @POST
    @Path("/compute")
    public void compute(){
        executor.execute(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                impl1.compute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Option 2 :

```
@Singleton
public class RestService {
    private Executor executor;
    private Implementation1 impl1;
    private Implementation2 impl2;

    public RestService () {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        impl1 = new Implementation1();
        impl2 = new Implementation2();
    }

    public void execute(Runnable run){
        executor.execute(run);
    }

    public Implementation1 getImplementation1(){
        return impl1;
    }

    public Implementation2 getImplementation2(){
        return impl2;
    }

}

@Path("/servicename")
public class MyService {

    @Inject
    private RestService rs;

    @POST
    @Path("/compute")
    public void compute(){
        rs.execute(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                rs.getImplementation1().compute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For option 1 I'm not sure about the "life cycle" about a static field. Which option should I use ? How would you do that ?

Thanks

**EDIT :**
Option 3 (thread handled by EJB Container) and "ordering" is not important :

```
@Singleton
public class RestService {
    private final Executor executor;
    private final Implementation1 impl1;
    private final Implementation2 impl2;

    public RestService () {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        impl1 = new Implementation1();
        impl2 = new Implementation2();
    }

    public void compute1(){
        executor.execute(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                impl1.compute();
            }
        });
    }

    public void compute2(){
        executor.execute(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                impl2.compute();
            }
        });
    }

}

@Path("/servicename")
public class MyService {

    @Inject
    private RestService rs;

    @POST
    @Path("/compute1")
    public void compute1(){
        rs.compute1();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/compute2")
    public void compute2(){
        rs.compute2();
    }
}
```

I think Option 3 is still better than Option 1 & 2.

Comment: if you can only execute one at once, I'd suggest you to use a queue such as JMS

Comment: I have already used JMS for a project, I think JMS is very heavy for this simple project.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's a bad idea to do this.  Threading ought to be handled by your container, not your code.

If you're deploying on a Java EE app server, you should let it handle the threading.

If you're deploying on a non-blocking I/O server like Netty or vert.x, you should let it handle the threading.

Under no circumstances should you be managing threads.

Static fields are instantiated when the .class loads.  They don't have a "lifecycle" the way instances do.  They won't be cleaned up until the class loader removes the .class file.

If you must have this kind of behavior, I'd either use a JMS queue to order the processing or a producer/consumer deque to manage it.  You want the processing to be asynch.  Let the REST service return a token or receipt to the client and have them come back to see when the processing is done.  If the line is long, you'll have no way to know when their shirt is ready.  The receipt lets them come back and check when their result is available.

Comment: I don't use Netty, vetr.x, JMS, but I can make the "threading part" inside my EJB container (@Singleton) : `@Path("/servicename")
public class MyService {

    @Inject
    private RestService rs;

    @POST
    @Path("/compute")
    public void compute(){
        rs.computeImplementation1(); // contains executor
    }
}` no ?

Comment: Maybe you can; I don't think you should.  Good luck to you.

Comment: I think that option 3 with a single thread pool managed by the Executor framework inside my EJB Container is not a so bad option. As an alternative, I may use JMS one day. Thank you for the advises, I can consider this subject as resolved (for the time being).

Answer (score 0):

If you used Spring, and then separated your business logic out into separate components (beans) and injected these beans into your service class you could effectively control the threading model of your implementation simply by changing the 'scope' attribute of your business logic beans.

Here's a [description of Spring bean scopes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm).

This approach would allow you to easily modify/experiment with your solution and discover the best alternative for your situation.

As far as architecture is concerned I would recommend that you layer your system(loose coupling, high cohesion, separation of concerns, etc.).  In this regard, you would probably have a service layer (REST), a business layer, and a data (dao) layer minimum.  The layers interact with each other via interfaces.  Use Spring to wire things together (inject dependencies).  This gives you the flexibility to inject different implementations.  Example would be to inject mock DAOs for your business classes for unit tests.  The service layer where your REST services live would perform the translation of requests/responses, some validation, determine which business components to invoke, and invoke them.

Comment: I don't need to use Spring, I have already an EJB Container and CDI annotations.